# Game on boolean String

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

Let $n\ge 2$ be a natural number. We consider the following game. Two players write a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s. They start with an empty line and alternate their moves. In each move, a player writes $0$ or $1$ at the end of the current sequence. A player loses if his digit completes a block of n consecutive digits that repeats itself in the sequence for the second time (two occurrences of the block may overlap).

For instance for $n=4$ a sequence produced by such a game would look as follows : $00100001101011110011$ ( the second player lost the last move because $0011$ is repeated)

Show that for $n=4$ ,the first player has a winning strategy.

---

For $n$  odd I have a winning strategy for the second player. The strategy is whatever the first player writes the second player writes the complement of it. But for $n=4$,  I have no idea how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: Source: Ex. 1.3.7(c) in "Invitation to Discrete Mathematics" by J. Matousek, J. Nesetril https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/40210/40210_F12/MNChapter1.pdf

Comment: Can you give your proof for odd $n$ please?

Comment: I did it with the help of induction on n (length of the block) . When n=1 my strategy works. Assume that my strategy works for n = some odd integer k. Now, I have to prove that it works on n = k+2. Assume that my strategy doesn't work for n=(k+2). Then in a sequence of 0's and 1's there exist a block of (k+2) digits completed by the second player which is repeated.But this cannot happen because this same sequence would generate a block of k digits completed by the second player which is repeated. Which contradicts my inductive hypothesis.